# dante not starting during server reboot

Tags: ubuntu, socks, dante, ubuntu-18.04

I installed dante (v1.4.2) using `apt-get install dante-server` on ubuntu 18.04 and have following configuration:

/etc/danted.conf

```
logoutput: /var/log/sockd.log

internal: eno1 port = 1080
external: eno1
external.rotation: same-same

socksmethod: username

user.privileged: root
user.unprivileged: nobody

client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect disconnect error
}

socks pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect disconnect error
}
```

When I run `service danted start` or `service danted restart` the service starts without any issue and the socks proxy works when using via my client.

But when I restart my server, the service fails to start with following status when running `service danted status`

[danted status screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wEMn.png)

Comment: you need to check output of `journalctl -u danted`

Comment: @TejasSarade it has same logs as mentioned on screenshot `danted.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1` and `danted.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and came across your question. I fixed it by adding a systemd dependency of network-online.target to the danted.service, based on reading this https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

Here's how:

```
sudo systemctl edit danted.service
```

add this:

```
    [Unit]
    After=network-online.target
    Wants=network-online.target
```

save & exit, run this for good measure

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable danted.service
```

Comment: Exactly this! Network interface simply wasn't online on time, so this solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Note for people stuck in the editor: Try CRTL+K and then Q to exit from the editor

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable this daemon in systemd

```
systemctl enable sockd.service
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: did this but still same error and not working

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo systemctl enable danted.service
```

After each boot/reboot the dante deamon will be started.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and tried `systemctl` an it does not work at all.

Finally I've used `crontab -e` adding this line:

```
@reboot sleep 10 && service danted restart
```

Now it works for me.